# How to access "insecure" services from HTTPS website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, security

In order to integrate Facebook authentication, I was forced to change my website connection type to "secure connection" (SSL Enabled - https://). Since then, when I try to access some services (ex: geonames) those services return an error.

Now I know that some services don't allow secure connections and others (geonames) only allow them for premium (payed) accounts.

Is there a way to establish "insecure connections" from a secure (https) website?

Comment: You can't do that; it defeats the whole purpose of security.

Comment: Hi SLaks! Ok, but in that case, that would mean that you can never add facebook authentication to a website that consumes insecure services. There must be some kind of "workaround" for this...

Comment: @mason: That's the opposite of his problem.  Facebook _requires_ SSL.

Comment: @LuisGouveia: You can make an SSL proxy to those services on your (SSL) server.

Comment: Slaks, I'll accept it as an answer if you want to :)